# How to add additional parameters to url?

Tags: html

Can anybody tell me how to add additional parameters to url? I have such code in my html file:

```
<a href="?lang=pl" [...]>
```

The url already has one parameter (.../show_more?id=12345) and I'd like this code above to add `lang=pl` at the end of url but my code replaces it. I tried using thymeleaf and `${#httpServletRequest.requestURL}`, but this url doesn't include parameters.

Answer (score 1):

[URI query parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) are separated by `&`

```
.../show_more?id=12345&lang=pl
```

Comment: I know, tried also `<a href="&lang=pl" [...]>`  but it still doesn't solve my problem... I want this link to work for every page, with or without parameters. I have a file with all common fragments of the page and use th:insert and this link is part of the commont fragment...